# Variable elimination in Bayes Net on a node with single child

Tags: artificial-intelligence

If we have a node `X`, that has a child `Y` in a Bayes net, why is it correct to express `P(Y)` as `P(Y|X)P(X)`?  Does it then follow that `X` is a necessary condition for `Y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bayes Networks

An edge in a Bayes Network means the variable is conditionally dependent. If nodes are not connected by any path, they are conditionally independent.

Having a node `X` with a child `Y` means you need to learn:

- Given `X` is True, what is the probability of `Y` being True?
- Given `X` is False, what is the probability of `Y` being True?

More generally: If X can have n values and Y can have m values, then you have to learn `n * (m - 1)` values. The `- 1` is there because the probabilities need to sum up to 1.

### Example

Let's stick with the simple case that both variables are binary and use the following from Wikipedia:

[image]

Say X is RAIN and Y is SPRINKLER. You want to express Y (SPRINKLER) in terms of X (RAIN).

The [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) states:

```
P(Y|X) = P(X|Y) * P(Y) / P(X)
<=> P(Y) = P(Y | X) * P(X) / P(X | Y)
```

Now we apply the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) for X. This means, for X we simply go through all possible values:

```
P(Y) = P(Y | X = true) * P(X = true) +
       P(Y | X = false) * P(X = false)
```

I guess this is what you refer to. `P(X=true | Y) = 1`, because the `X=true` means we already know that `X=true` happened. It doesn't matter what Y is.

To continue our case, we now look up the values in the tables (X is RAIN, Y is SPRINKLER):

```
P(Y) = 0.01 * 0.2 + 0.4 * 0.8
     = 0.322
```